# google script on cancel

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a script for Google Sheets. 
The script takes a long time to run, so Google show the following message on top of the sheet: "Running script Cancel Dismiss" (which is OK).

When I click on "Cancel", I would like the gs code to clean up the the current state. Is there a way to hook code to this event? Or is there a way to execute a piece of code before finishing the execution?

Comment: can you share code please?

Comment: No, you can't run code when the user says "stop running code"

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to catch the "cancel" signal from within your script.

If you have a lot of cleanup which must not be skipped, you can use the `PropertiesService`[1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/) to set a script property (or user property if the cleanup is per-user). The timestamp of the last run is not a bad idea.

Then, at the start of your long-running script, you can set that property to now (`new Date()`) and clear it at the end of healthy execution. Before you do *that* you could check (by name) whether the property is already set, and do some cleanup if it is (since presumably the prior invocation died).

You'll notice that you might step on yourself if you try concurrent runs, such as from multiple tabs. For this, you'll want a `Lock`[2](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/). The concept is simple: when you start you acquire a lock which prevents other invocations from getting that lock (blocking by default).

So the logic basically goes:

1. Start script
2. See if you can acquire the lock.

   1. If so, acquire it (with a timeout!) and proceed.
   2. If not, either wait for exit as appropriate.
3. See if the `lastRun` property is set.

   1. If so, no other process has the lock so nothing is running, but we're due a cleanup. Run `cleanUp()` which should clear `lastRun` as its last action
   2. If not, it should be safe to run
4. Set the property
5. Do stuff
6. Run `cleanUp()` which should clear the `lastRun` property as its last action
7. Release the lock
8. Exit cleanly

As code, this might look like:

```
function scriptMain() {
    var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
    lock.waitLock(30000);
    var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
    var lastRun = scriptProperties.getProperty('last run time');
    if (lastRun != null) { cleanUp(); }
    scriptProperties.setProperty('last run time', new Date());  // aka now

    // Do Stuff

    cleanUp();
    lock.releaseLock();
    return();

function cleanUp() {
    var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();  // or just pass it in

    // Do actual cleanup

    scriptProperties.deleteProperty('last run time'); // subsequent GETs will return null
    return;
```